# Stuck with an query that getting async error

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a controller which contains the following:

```
List<Game> gamesRat = new List<Game>();
        if (selectedRating.Count() != 0)//User select any checkboxes
        {
            FilterGamesByRating(gamesRat, selectedRating, "Shooter");//Filter by user inputs
            my = true;//Boolean
        }
```

So the my question is:
when I try to return a View:

```
return View(await PaginatedList<Game>.CreateAsync(gamesRat.AsQueryable(), page ?? 1, pSize));
```

I get the following error:

> The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations

But when in other method, I put that query:

```
IQueryable<Game> games = _context.Games.Where(x => x.Category == "Shooter");
return View(await PaginatedList<Game>.CreateAsync(games, page ?? 1, pSize));
```

It works perfectly. How can I fix that error? Thanks.

Of course, my PaginatedList method:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message is clear. The `XyzAsync` extension methods are non standard and cannot be used on LINQ to Objects `IQueryable<T>` implementation (which you get by using `List<T>.AsQueryable()`). Either create sync version of your `Create` method (e.g. `public static PaginatedList<T> Create(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)` or make sure you use only real EF `IQueryable<T>` implementations.